# Power BI while loop

Tags: while-loop, powerbi, m

I'm trying to do a while loop in Power BI M language. But all of the logic are all over my head!

How would you translate a very simple loop like this into M language?

`while X == True:
    do abcdef
    if Y == True:
       end`

Thanks very much!

Comment: Both M and DAX are more oriented towards working with columns rather than loops, so the best answer is dependent on what you're trying to do. Sometimes you do really need a loop, but much of the time there's a better way to achieve your goal within the language. What are you trying to do to a table that you want to use a loop for?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying repeatedly make an API call and only stop when the server is ready. That's why I had to resort to using a loop.

Comment: Gotcha. That does sound like you probably do have to resort to a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops in M are probably best handled with the [`List.Generate` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate).

This article does a pretty good job at explaining how it works:
https://potyarkin.ml/posts/2017/loops-in-power-query-m-language/

Using this function, let's look at a more specific implementation of a while loop, say to find Fibonacci numbers less than 1000.

```
a = 1
b = 1
while b < 1000
    b = a + b
    a = b - a
```

would translate to M something like this:

```
let
    data =
    List.Generate(
        () => [ a = 1, b = 1 ],
        each [b] < 1000,
        each [ b = [a] + [b], a = [b] ]
    ),
    output = Table.FromRecords(data)[a]
in output
```

---

I'm not sure the best way to handle your break condition `Y`. It might depend on the specific problem.